# Running Query of pgRouting and PostGIS - dijkstra_sp_delta()?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, postgresql-10

Using

> PostgreSQL 10.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit 
>   PostGIS 2.4.4 
>   pgRouting 2.6.0

and [This Tutorial](https://pgrouting.org/docs/foss4g2007/ch04.html) I am trying to run this Query

```
$conn = pg_connect($conString);
$sql = "SELECT gid, AsText(geom) AS wkt,
           length(geom) AS length, ".TABLE.".id
        FROM ".TABLE.",
            (SELECT gid, geom
                FROM dijkstra_sp_delta(
                    '".TABLE."',
                    ".$startEdge['source'].",
                    ".$endEdge['target'].",
                    3000)
             ) as rt
        WHERE ".TABLE.".gid=gid;";
$query = pg_query($conn,$sql);
```

but I am getting this error:

> Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: function
>   dijkstra_sp_delta(unknown, integer, integer, integer) does not exist
>   LINE 5: FROM dijkstra_sp_delta( ^ HINT: No function matches the given
>   name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. in
>   D:\wamp64\www\Route\assets\post.php on line 46

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you defined TABLE?

Comment: Hi , thanks for reply, yes I did. I even pass the table name directly `victoria` and getting same error back

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you're trying to follow is from FOSS4G conference in 2007, and pgRouting has changed a lot since then.

You need to update your pgRouting functions to the current version. But more easy would be to start with the pgRouting workshop: https://workshop.pgrouting.org/

Comment: Thanks for comment but the latest workshops are not using any PHP model!

Comment: Yes, but they use the current SQL queries. It shouldn't be too difficult to change apply the new SQL syntax to PHP.